# Rotating PDF/raster in QGIS 2

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, qgis-2, pdf, rotate

In QGIS 2.14.0-Essen I inserted a PDF (image) in my work.

But the PDF is rotated 180 degrees...
My objective is to georeferencing it.

How can I rotate it prior to georeferencing it?

Comment: Can you expand more what you mean by "I inserted a pdf (image) in my work"?

Comment: Yes. I added a raster layer (a pdf that is not georeferenced).

Comment: Why do you want to rotate it before georeferencing it?  The process of georeferencing it will rotate it for you.

Comment: you're right.. so sorry. The processo was almost automatic. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, no need to rotate before loading the image because the process of georeferencing will rotate it.